# Toggling individual elements of the same class in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript

I am building a dropdown menu. As is, when I open one submenu, it stays open, even if I open a second submenu. When I open the second submenu, it should close any other open menus.

```js
const submenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.has-submenu > a');
submenuLinks.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var submenu = element.nextElementSibling;
    if (submenu.classList.contains('menu-hide')) { 
        submenu.classList.add('menu-show');
        submenu.classList.remove('menu-hide');
    } else {
        submenu.classList.add('menu-hide');
        submenu.classList.remove('menu-show');
    }
}));
```

```css
.menu-hide {
    display: none;
}

.menu-show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#">Menu Item 2 &raquo;</a>
            <ul class="menu-sub menu-hide">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#">Menu Item 3 &raquo;</a>
            <ul class="menu-sub menu-hide">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no need to use two different classes to show and hide the submenus.
- You can hide all submenus by default with CSS and only show the one with
  `.menu-show`

Try this

```js
const submenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.has-submenu > a');
submenuLinks.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var submenu = element.nextElementSibling;
    if (submenu.classList.contains('menu-show')) {
        submenu.classList.remove('menu-show');
    } else {
        submenuLinks.forEach(a => a.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('menu-show'));
        submenu.classList.add('menu-show');
    }
}));
```

```css
.menu-sub {
    display: none;
}

.menu-show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#">Menu Item 2 &raquo;</a>
            <ul class="menu-sub">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#">Menu Item 3 &raquo;</a>
            <ul class="menu-sub">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

before your logic that hides the current submenu, you can hide every submenu (ul with class 'menu-sub'). In this way, only the current submenu will be expanded. Here's the edited javascript code:

```
const submenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.has-submenu > a');

    submenuLinks.forEach((element) =>
      element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var allSubmenus = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-sub');
        allSubmenus.forEach((submenu) => {
          submenu.classList.remove(...submenu.classList);
          submenu.classList.add('menu-sub');
          submenu.classList.add('menu-hide');
        });
        var currentSubmenu = element.nextElementSibling;
        if (currentSubmenu.classList.contains('menu-hide')) {
          currentSubmenu.classList.add('menu-show');
          currentSubmenu.classList.remove('menu-hide');
        } else {
          currentSubmenu.classList.add('menu-hide');
          currentSubmenu.classList.remove('menu-show');
        }
      })
    );
```

What I did there extra was to remove all the classes from the submenus, add back the 'menu-sub' and 'menu-hide' classes.

Answer (score 1):

You must loop over all ul's to check the classes. I commented what i add to you js code.

```js
  const uls = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-sub');
  uls.forEach(a => {
      if (a.classList.contains('menu-show')) {        
        a.classList.remove('menu-show')  
        a.classList.add('menu-hide')  
      }      
    })
```

```js
const submenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.has-submenu > a');

submenuLinks.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  /* start */
  const uls = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-sub');
  uls.forEach(a => {
      if (a.classList.contains('menu-show')) {        
        a.classList.remove('menu-show')  
        a.classList.add('menu-hide')  
      }      
    })
  /* end */
    var submenu = element.nextElementSibling;
    if (submenu.classList.contains('menu-hide')) { 
        submenu.classList.add('menu-show');
        submenu.classList.remove('menu-hide');
    } else {
        submenu.classList.add('menu-hide');
        submenu.classList.remove('menu-show');
    }
}));
```

```css
.menu-hide {
    display: none;
}

.menu-show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#">Menu Item 2 &raquo;</a>
            <ul class="menu-sub menu-hide">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#">Menu Item 3 &raquo;</a>
            <ul class="menu-sub menu-hide">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```